# What is this Javascript gallery called?

Tags: javascript, gallery, javascript-objects

What do you call [this gallery](http://www.thebucketlistfamily.com/about/)? The gallery I'm referring to begins with an image of a family in a paint studio. I believe they're using JavaScript. 
My end goal is to be able to code it - but not knowing it's name makes that difficult.

Comment: Please see bullet point #4 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Your question is very vague and does not lend itself to a concise answer related to software development.

Comment: @MikeCollins The question is clearly asking what you would call the gallery at the provided URL. Definitely off-topic, but hardly vague.

Comment: @Snijman Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here, so I'm voting to close it. However, if you're talking about the image with the list of clickable thumbnails underneath, you might try searching for "image carousel" or "image slideshow" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page source for http://www.thebucketlistfamily.com/about/

The website is developed using Squarespace https://www.squarespace.com/

Here you can see the User Interface regarding the gallery https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpWVm1S8GLo

GIST to get you started https://gist.github.com/iwatakeshi/95fc070a668198566588

You would need to implement your own image gallery / carousel, but this is made easy utilizing existing tools:

https://www.google.co.nz/search?ei=fRW0WtKzKsWk0gSnqoGwBg&q=javascript+carousel&oq=javascript+carousel&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.0.0.0.38731.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DYnHzIRbiH4

Hope this helps.